# SQL Select if substring occurs then copy until substring else keep original

Tags: mysql, sql, string, substring

I have a database with TV Guide data, and in my description field (VARCHAR) sometimes i have a '|' where behind it is the rating. I used to check this in php, before converting it all to XML, but i would like to do this in SQL.

So if i have this string:

```
This is the description | rating pg-13
```

Then i want to keep the

```
This is the description
```

**but** if there is no '|' i want the whole string.
I tried using substring, but can't get it to work.

My query now is:

```
SELECT *, SUBSTRING(`long_description`, 1, POSITION('|' IN `long_description`)) FROM `programs` WHERE station_id = 1
```

this works only one way - this gives me the string before the '|' but if there is no '|' it gives an empty column.

Comment: Personally I would say it is better have the description and rating as separate columns. What if you want to aggregate ratings - EG "how many PG-13 movies do we have?"

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I am using Mysql, Gordon Linoff's awnser works for me, and yes Searle1986 that might be a good idea, ill update my scraper script - but it depends on websites, some websites have a | in the description and some dont

Comment: The complete SQL Query now looks like this:
`SELECT *, 
DATE_FORMAT(programstart,'%Y%m%d%h%i%s') AS xmltv_start, 
DATE_FORMAT(programend,'%Y%m%d%h%i%s') as xmltv_end,  
substring_index(long_description, '|', 1)  AS description
FROM `programs
WHERE station_id = $station_index`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the use of backticks, you might be using MySQL.  If so, `substring_index()` does exactly what you want:

```
select substring_index(long_description, '|', 1)
```

Comment: Thank you!! That did the trick :) i thought i needed a if else statement, but this works. This is 10x faster than checking in php..

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    IF(long_description LIKE '%|%',
        SUBSTRING(`long_description`,
            1,
            POSITION('|' IN `long_description`)),
        long_description)
FROM
    `programs`
WHERE
    station_id = 1
```

The `IF` clause basically just checks if you have a `|` in the field and applies your routine when this is true. Else it will simply return the complete `long_description` value.

Comment: Thank you, this one worked also, but the awnser Gordon Linoff gave is a bit shorter, and works perfectly in my complete query.